# What is the functionality in initializing some value like -1, 0, or 1 to variables?

Tags: c

I was given a problem and had to write some code for it. The context of the problem is as follows:

"Consider this data sequence: '3 11 5 5 5 2 4 6 6 7 3 -8'. Any value that is the same as the immediately preceding value is considered a CONSECUTIVE DUPLICATE. In this example, there are three such consecutive duplicates: the 2nd and 3rd 5s and the second 6. Note that the last 3 is not a consecutive duplicate because it was preceded by a 7.

Write some code that uses a loop to read such a sequence of non-negative integers, terminated by a negative number. When the code exits the loop it should print the number of consecutive duplicates encountered. In the above case, that value would be 3."

So I got the code down after a couple of tries and looking at references to similar codes online. The problem I'm having is figuring out why variables duplicates and secondNumber are assigned to a specific value and why firstNumber shouldn't have any variables assigned to it.

```
#include<stdio.h>

{
    int firstNumber;
    int secondNumber = -8;
    int duplicates = 0;

do {
    scanf("%d", &firstNumber);
        if ( secondNumber == -8) {
            secondNumber = firstNumber;
        }
        else {
            if ( secondNumber == firstNumber )
                duplicates++;
            else
                secondNumber = firstNumber;
        }
} while(firstNumber > 0 );

    printf("%d", duplicates);
}
```

Of course, I ran the program with the given numbers and it worked, but I'm just having too much trouble wrapping my head around how -8 and 0 play into the whole code.

Comment: That code will not compile

Comment: Uninitialized local variables will have an *indeterminate* value (that might seem like random or garbage). If you want a variable to have a specific value you must initialize it or assign to it. Depending on type and the "random" value, using the variable uninitialized could lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Just play around giving the variables deliberate other values, including changed signs and so on. Use a debugger or insert some `printf()` to see the effects. Then you will see why.

Comment: So it is _your_ code, and you are asking why _you_ have initialised some variables and not others?  Something is not right here, although to be honest all the pre-amble to your question is probably irrelevant.  It is better to get straight down to the question.

Comment: The provided sequence is not a _"sequence of non-negative integers"_ it inexplicably has a -8 value.  It appears to be a sentinel value, in which case it is not part of the sequence.

Comment: Your code is more complex than necessary.  It it is a simple matter of incrementing `duplicates` whenever a value is equal to the previous value.

Answer (score -1):

The condition for terminating the program operation must be a negative number entered. Instead of -8, there can be any negative number, it's just the key that forces you to enter the second number. About zero I will not answer - explain which zero interests you.

Comment: If you consider the question to be incomplete, you should post a _comment_ requesting clarification rather than commenting about it in your _answer_.  Only one variable is initialised to zero in any case, so it seems clear what is referred to, but the question is more generally about the need to initialise _any_ variable to _any_value at all.  The -8 _initialisation_ is not about terminating the loop, rather it ensures that the first value does not cause `duplicates` to be incremented, which would happen in this case if it contained 3 which could happen without explicit initialisation.

Answer (score -1):

okay, so let's review

- input has a set of non-negative integers
- input ends with a negative number

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    {
        int firstNumber; //no need to initialize since it is read from user
        int secondNumber = -8; //the value has no meaning other then it is 
                               //negative, following the end input termination
                               //it is used for the first comparison, since it 
                               //is stated that the input ends with a negative 
                               //number we can assure that a negative number will 
                               //not produce a false positive

        int duplicates = 0; //this variable is used as a counter - it must be
                            //initialized, otherwise duplicates++ will yield
                            // unexpected behavior

    do {
        scanf("%d", &firstNumber);
            if ( secondNumber == -8) { //this condition will evaluate to true
                                       //only on the first iteration of the loop
                secondNumber = firstNumber;
            }
            else {
                if ( secondNumber == firstNumber )
                    duplicates++;
                else
                    secondNumber = firstNumber;
            }
    } while(firstNumber > 0 ); //this is actually a bug the work statement said 
                               //non-negative integer, 0 is a valid input value
        printf("%d", duplicates);
    }
```

- please consider what happens when the list has 0 values so it is just the end condition i.e. a negative number
- the condition `secondNumber == -8` will only be evaluated as true once, but it is checked every time, perhaps the code can be improved

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Local non-static variables without an explicit initialiser have *undefined* value.  So initialisation is required when the value will be read before it is otherwise explicitly assigned.

It is possible to declare without initialisation, and then explicitly *assign* a value before the value needs to be read. For example:

```
int duplicates ;
duplicates = 0 ;
```

But using explicit initialisation (i.e. assigning a value on creation of teh variable) closes the window during which the variable has undefined value. This can avoid bugs where you might read a variable before it has ever been assigned a value.  In that sense it is generally considered *good practice* to initialise all non-static local variables.

The first thing the code does is *assign* `firstNumber` (via `scanf()`)  so initialisation is not required, but would do no harm, and is often advised to avoid undefined behaviour.

`secondNumber` is tested for value *before* it is assigned, so must have a value.  The test `secondNumber == -8` will be true on the first iteration.  The use of -8 seems arbitrary any negative value could be used, -1 would be more idiomatic.

Again `duplicates` is modified before it is assigned a value, and is a count of consecutive duplicates so must be initialised to zero.

The question says nothing about how the sequence is presented and can be generalised:

```
int dupCount( int* seq )
{
    int duplicates = 0 ;
    for( int i = 1; seq[i] >= 0; i++ )
    {
        if( seq[i] == seq[i-1] )
        {
            duplicates++ ;
        }
    }

    return duplicates ;
}
```

Example usage:

```
int main()
{
    int seq[] = {3, 11, 5, 5, 5, 2, 4, 6, 6, 7, 3, -1} ;
    printf( "%d\n", dupCount( seq ) ) ;

    return 0;
}
```

If arbitrary length user input is specified and simply omitted from your question, then:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int inputDupCount()
{
    int inp = 0 ;
    scanf( "%d", &inp ) ;

    int duplicates = 0 ;
    while( inp > 0 )
    {
        int prev_inp = inp ;
        scanf( "%d", &inp ) ;

        if( inp == prev_inp )
        {
            duplicates++ ;
        }
    }

    return duplicates ;
}
```

Usage example:

```
int main()
{
    printf( "%d\n", inputDupCount() ) ;
    return 0;
}
```